# Linux -> Terminal command -> Grep -> Expressions / Exceptions related to symbol

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

Simply: I have problem with command which should print me lines containing any of those two expressions: "**king"** , **"king's son"**. This is where I got so far:

```
grep -w "king's son\|king" frog.txt
```

It does work but it include **"king's"** which *should not* happen.

Adding *`-v grep "king's"`* does not work as it deletes **"king's son"** also.

I am using Ubuntu 32 bit system installed on Virtual Box Machine.

Comment: Since you're having trouble with getting correct answers from other users, please consider leaving the content of `frog.txt`.

Comment: I got an answer which was solution of my problem : http://stackoverflow.com/a/30550218/4956820

Comment: I'm sorry, I overlooked it, maybe because it's not upvoted nor accepted. If that answer is in fact the solution to your problem you should at least accept it. whereswalden and future readers will most certainly appreciate it. :)

Comment: I rolled back your final edit. Checking an answer to accept it is completely sufficient; the question should remain just a question, not commentary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This oughta do it:

```
grep -E "(^|[ \t])(king|king's son)([ \t]|$)" frog.txt
```

It uses the groups `(^|[ \t])` and `([ \t]|$)` to match word separators or the beginning/end of lines.

Comment: It works, thank you for your response. It works without failure avoiding adding things like "king's castle" and stuff. Thank you once again. Please plus this answer so someone who will be in same situation as me would find solution.

Answer (score 3):

`-w` won't help much because `king` is considered a word in `king's` as `'` is a non-word character.

Use:

```
grep -E "([[:space:]]|^)king('s son)?([[:space:]]|$)" frog.txt
```

Or using **lookarounds** if your `grep` has PCRE option available:

```
grep -P "(?<=[[:space:]]|^)king('s son)?(?=[[:space:]]|$)" frog.txt
```

Comment: None of them works, second one is giving me lines with "breaking" as well.

Comment: Both of these commands are working. In case there is a possibility of tab character after `king` then use: `grep -E "king('s son)?([[:space:]]|$)" frog.txt`

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -E "([[:space:]]|^)king('s son)?([[:space:]]|$)" frog.txt
```

For example, if `frog.txt` contains

```
kingb    # no match
king's   # no match
king-bee # no match 
breaking # no match
king's hello # no match
king's sonth # no match

king     # match
a king bee  # match
king    bee # match (with a TAB)
king's son  # match
```

then the above command returns

```
king     # match
a king bee  # match
king    bee # match (with a TAB)
king's son  # match
```

Comment: They both return lines with "king's son" only.

Comment: `\s` is not a  valid metaexpression for whitespace in most `grep` dialects. Try replacing it with `[[:space:]]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -w "king's son\|king$" frog.txt
```

Comment: It shows only lines containing "king's son" which is not result which I wanted to get. Thank you for response.

Answer (score 0):

the following line maybe work for your situation.

```
grep -w "king's son\|king$\|king\ " frog.txt
```

the result is :

```
king's son   #match
king         #match
king's hello #not match
```

Comment: @Advent: Please tell us *how* it doesn't work. Give an example where it fails. Then perhaps we can improve the answer.

Comment: can you give some examples  ?

Comment: This command sends me to text style where it gets stucked and I cannot quit it with other way than closing terminal. It does nothing, at least for me.